# When is institutional change no longer possible?

Tags: career-development, company-culture, promotion, research

I'm been at an R&D organisation for the last 5 years. When I joined I was in a mid level position within a 7 person team. The team was hyper focused on a single goal and we had support from the larger 35+ person team. Over the last 5 years we've had some hard times and people starting dropping off one by one and replacements haven't happened. My skills have also grown over the last 5 years so that we haven't had much of a functional drop off in the team. I've been bringing this up again and again with my line manager, his one, and the one above that (this organisation is stupidly vertical). The outcome has generally been "we appreciate all the hard work but, regretfully, nothing is going to change".

The current situation is:

- The 7 person team is now 2 people (me and a junior dude). Most of the people who've left have received 50+% pay increases. I've fought tooth and nail to replace people but no advertisements ever get sent out.
- the 35+ larger team is now down to ~15 people.
- Many of the contracts we've been working on have been renewed, so the financials are looking better. I've also managed to secure a couple new projects. We're still profitable.
- I'm currently responsible for the business dev, database, research direction, maintenance, client hand holding, student supervision, writing proposals etc. It's been a great learning opportunity but you'd be insane to think any of my outputs are fantastic
- I haven't done any new R&D in the last 2 years
- My promotion paperwork was "lost" last year, there's no interim promotions/salary increases and the next round "should be" happening before the end of the year. I honestly think it fell between the cracks since the whole place has been operating like a circus fire.
- I'm frequently expected to provide strategic direction and support to people outside the team that are 2 or 3 pay levels above me.
- I'm unlikely to get promoted more than a single level because I won't meet the boilerplate requirements for "Human Capital Development" (since I'm essentially running a one man show), or publications (since I have no time for R&D). This place is very bureaucratic...
- The work we're doing has real world impact. If I leave there's a non trivial chance that the project is going belly-up since we've lost so much institutional knowledge, documentation has been very poor and we're involved in PhD level R&D work so finding replacements is really had. Because of the nature of the work, funding requirements and reputation of the organisation the current projects wouldn't function in the private sector.

I've started looking around at other organisations and there are a handful of possibilities out there but they generally require international relocation. I'm just having a hard time pulling the trigger on this. I keep telling myself things will get better but I'm becoming bitter and I'm concerned that the lack of novel work is hurting my career. I'm also very concerned about the project dying, I've stuck a good few years into it and it's pretty successful.

So my questions:

- How long does institutional change take? Is it unreasonable to expect a large (1000+) organisation to make changes within 12 months?
- Is it normal to change organisations but to keep roles very similar?
- Is "forced uncomfortable growth" good for career progression or is it usually better to be more focused?

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace. I'm struggling to see the actual specific question you'd like help with here - it's obvious you're pretty frustrated with your current work, but we can't tell you whether to relocate or not as that's a personal choice only you can make. Could you try and edit your question to make it clearer what questions you'd like answered? Thanks!

Comment: I'm very emotional about this so it is very close to a rant. I'm not sure what the question is rather than just screaming into the void and hoping for an answer. I'll try be a little more specific

Comment: Unfortunately your updated question isn't really a good fit here either, as the answer to all three is "it depends". Some institutions change very quickly (particularly if driven from the top), some change very, very slowly. Sometimes organisation change results in the same roles, sometimes it doesn't, depends on why the change is happening.

Comment: Righto, I'm more used to the technical exchanges. If this question isn't appropriate then feel free to get rid of it.., Framing the question/rant has already helped me a bit

Comment: `How long does institutional change take? Is it unreasonable to expect a large (1000+) organisation to make changes within 12 months?` - You state that as if it's an obligation on the company's part. It isn't. If the company hasn't and isn't changing then your only option is to leave.

Comment: The ones that left have received 50+% pay increases. Why are you still there? It seems you have been underpaid for years. Why do you think the company has any interest in changing that?

Comment: I earn enough to live a comfortable life. I've also had a couple windfalls that means I could happily live without any salary for a few years. I've got no debt. All combined means that money isn't really much of a motivator for me but the "opportunity cost" of staying is a bit grating. I'm also very much emotionally invested in the project I'm working on. It has demonstrable "public good" impact and the team managing it is almost all gone. If I go there's a pretty good chance it'll be put years back or die completely

Answer (score 4):

> How long does institutional change take? Is it unreasonable to expect a large (1000+) organisation to make changes within 12 months?

That depends a lot on the leadership and corporate culture. I've seen companies that size turn on a dime, but it's rare and unusual. For anything that's more "conservative" like academia, government or public funding, etc, this is probably a non-starters. In any case it would require an external forcing funding, i.e. massive business pressure. From what you describe this highly unlikely in your case.

> Is it normal to change organisations but to keep roles very similar?

Yes. It's a clear sign of "fake change" which is unfortunately fairly common. In reaction to some event, external pressure, or a request from the powers-at-be the company must execute some change although they don't want to. So some org charts get redrawn some job titles get creatively re-invented, but none of the values, behaviors of workflows get tackled. It's just enough so can you show to the stake holders that "we are changing".

> Is "forced uncomfortable growth" good for career progression or is it usually better to be more focused?

Surprisingly the answer is mostly "yes, being uncomfortable is good for your career". Within reason, that is. Being outside your comfort zone, keeps you on your toes and you learn a variety of skills and coping mechanisms that you otherwise wouldn't. It's like going to the gym: no pain, no gain. Obviously it's a matter of balance, but its sounds that you are learning a lot of interesting and valuable skills in your current gig.

**Summary**

You org is NOT going to change. You need to decide whether you are fine with the status quo or move on.

One source on discomfort:
https://www.forbes.com/sites/sujanpatel/2016/03/09/why-feeling-uncomfortable-is-the-key-to-success/#2034723b1913

Answer (score 2):

You've already answered your own question: **the institution is not going to change and you're not in a position to force it to change**.

The actual question is whether you should accept this and stay, or leave.  Since you sound pretty unhappy with your pay, workload,.lack of career progression and lack of promotions prospects, and you've started looking at other options, it sounds to me like you've answered this one too and have already decided to leave as soon as a good opportunity comes along.